# How do you upload json files using php?

Tags: php, json, file-upload

I am trying to upload a JSON file to the server of 000webhost. I was using a tutorial from w3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp, but I have removed all the file checks since these would block json files. This is the `upload.php` code. I think it's not necessary to have it as a php file but I tried everything I could think of.

```html
<form action="upload_action.php" method="POST" encType="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="uploadForm" name='uploadForm'><br>
    <input class='hidden' id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

This is the `upload_action.php` code:

```php
<?php
$target_dir = "datasets/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["uploadForm"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
  echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadForm"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["uploadForm"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
  } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  }
}
?>
```

It works with any other file type that I've tried.

Comment: `It works with any other file type` What do you mean by this?

Comment: What exactly goes wrong when you submit a JSON file? Which message do you get? Does PHP report any errors, warnings or notices?

Comment: This is the error I get Notice: Undefined index: uploadForm in /storage/ssd5/200/16700200/public_html/html/upload_action.php on line 6

Comment: By any other file type I mean images, pdf, csv and word documents to be more precise

Answer (score 0):

Note that you dont update `uploadOk` before checking `$uploadOk == 0`. However this isn't the problem for uploading process. I guess your file size exceeds the maximum file size allowed by 000webhost. Try again with a test JSON file to make sure it's not about the file size. Also make sure you have a "tmp" directory beside `public_html` directory.

Comment: Thanks it is the file size that's the problem, if I use a smaller file it does work